# Can we keep first element as a blank while declaring constant using useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can we write

```
const [, setOpenCollapse] = React.useState(false);
```

? Is this a valid syntax if I kept first element as a blank while declaring constant using useState in React?

Comment: I think you can use an underscore (_) like this
```const [_, setOpenCollapse] = React.useState(false);```

Comment: Did you try it? This isn't specific to React/hooks, just basic JS array destructuring syntax.

Comment: Why would you declare a state if you are not using it?

Comment: I think it's a perfectly valid syntax. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @André - Yes that's perfect why would anyone declare a state if he/she are not using it? 

---- Asked this, just for a curiosity.

Comment: _"Any other thoughts?"_ Syntax validity isn't a matter of opinion, you find can trivially find out.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think it clears the threshold for syntax questions. It boils down to whether this is valid array destructuring syntax and is covered by the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#ignoring_some_returned_values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically this code is valid, it will compile. However, when writing like this you will have no reference to the state and therefore won't be able to use it.
There is no point in having a state if you are not using it.